# How branching programs with small width are related to Turing machines with small space?

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity

The complexity book by Arora and Barak mentions that "branching programs of constant width (reminiscent of a TM with O(1) bits of memory) seem inherently weak." I am not able to figure out how both are connected. Can anyone here shed a light on this?